# Proof that non-well-orderable sets are not equinumerous to their own cardinals (using Scott's trick)

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Azriel Levy's Basic Set Theory (the 2002 Dover edition) contains the following problem (Chapter 3, Exercise 2.24):

> Prove that $|x|$ is an ordinal iff $|x| \approx x$, (i.e., iff $|\,|x|\,| = |x|$). If $\mathfrak{a}$ is not a well-ordered cardinal then $|\mathfrak{a}| > \mathfrak{a}$.
>
> Hint. Use the fact that for infinite $\alpha$, $R(\alpha) \times 2 \approx R(\alpha)$, thus $R(\alpha)$ includes two disjoint
> copies of itself.

$R(\alpha)$ is defined as the set of sets whose ranks are strictly less than $\alpha$.

The book uses the following definition of cardinal numbers:

> The cardinal of $x$, or, synonymously, the cardinality of $x$, which we
> shall denote by $|x|$, is
>
> (a) the least ordinal $\alpha$ equinumerous to $x$, if $x$ is well-orderable, and
>
> (b) the set of all sets $y$ of least rank which is equinumerous to $x$, otherwise.

In other words, it uses representative ordinals for well-orderable sets, and Scott's trick for non-well-orderable ones.

The part of this problem I am specifically having trouble with is proving that if $|x|$ is not an ordinal, then $|x| \not\approx x$. The two proof techniques that I can think of which seem relevant are some kind of diagonalization argument, or assuming that $|x| \approx x$ and using the relevant bijection to obtain a well-ordering of $x$. However, after spending several hours thinking about this problem, I cannot come up with a successful way of doing either.

I'm pretty sure that the hint is not relevant here (I found it useful in proving the second sentence of the problem, given the truth of the first, so I assume that's the part it was intended for).

This doesn't seem like a problem that is intended to be this difficult, so I think have probably overlooked something. Any help solving it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Whoops, don't know how I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $|x|$ is *not* an ordinal. Then the element of $|x|$ is not well-orderable, so $x$ also is. By the definition of $|x|$, every $y\in |x|$ has the same rank, let it call $\alpha$. Then $|x|\subseteq R(\alpha+1)$, and we may assume $x\subseteq R(\alpha)$.

Let $f:R(\alpha)\times R(\alpha)\to R(\alpha)$ be a bijection. Observe that for each $y\in |x|$, $y$ is a subset of $R(\alpha)$. Now consider $f^"[y\times \{a\}]\subseteq R(\alpha)$ for each $a\in R(\alpha)$. Then we have $|R(\alpha)|$ pairwise disjoint copies of elements of $|x|$.
Hence $|R(\alpha)|\le |\,|x|\,|$. Moreover, $x\subseteq R(\alpha)$ proves $|x|\le |R(\alpha)|$.

If $|x|<|R(\alpha)|$, then obviously $|x|<|\,|x|\,|$.
Now assume that $|x|=|R(\alpha)|$. Without loss of generality, assume that $x=R(\alpha)$. I claim that $R(\alpha+1)$ has $|R(\alpha+1)|=2^{|R(\alpha)|}$ copies of $R(\alpha)$. In fact, we can prove

> **Claim** If $|X|=|X|^2$, then $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has $2^{|X|}$ copies of $X$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $f: X\times X\to X$ be a bijection. Then we have a family of pairwise disjoint sets $X_a:=f^"[\{a\}\times X]$ and a family of bijections $f(a,-): X\to X_a$.
>
> For each $A\subseteq X$, consider
> $$Y_A = \bigcup_{a\in A}X_a.$$
> Then $|X|\le |Y_A|= |A|\times |X|\le |X|^2=|X|$. (Proving $|Y_A|= |A|\times |X|$ requires the uniform family of bijections.)
> Since $A\neq B$ implies $Y_A\neq Y_B$, we are done.

It proves $|\,|R(\alpha)|\,|=2^{|R(\alpha)|}$.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for $2|V(\alpha)|= |V_\alpha|$ and $|V(\alpha)\times V(\alpha)| = |V(\alpha)|$? It's the first I've seen this. The first immediately implies the second at successor stages, but seems to require the first bijection to be canonical in order to work at limit stages. But it also seems like the proof by induction of the first one does produce a canonical bijection. Do I have that right?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I realized that these two equalities are not trivial as I had thought. I also agree that we can construct the bijection for the equalities canonically. I will add the proof of them (or delete the answer if I am wrong.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Thank you for your answer! I have come up with proofs of both equalities that give canonical injections. Would it be more appropriate to add them as an edit to my question, or to your answer? (This is my first time asking a question here and I'm not entirely certain of community etiquette.) Also, I'm pretty sure you don't even need the second equality for your proof. If you use $R(\alpha) \times 2$ and replace $y\times \{a\}$ with $(y\times\{0\}) \cup {\langle a, 1 \rangle}$, you should get the same result, since the subsets just need to be distinct, not disjoint.

Comment: @aronszajn I have no idea about the etiquette, but it would be better to put the proof in your question or put it as a separate answer, to distinguish my work and your own.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Start with a fixed bijection between $V_\omega$ and $V_\omega^2$, call it $f_0$, and you can even take it to be canonical (compose the Ackermann function with the Cantor pairing function). Now we can use that to construct an explicit bijection $g\colon V_{\omega+1}\to V_{\omega+1}^2$, call it $f_1$; recursively continue. When we reach a limit step, we have the sequence of the functions $f_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\delta$ (our limit). So no choice is needed.